# product of elements coming from distinct annihilators

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a finite commutative ring with unity. Let $a,b \in R$ be such that $a \in ann(x)$, $b \in ann(y)$ and $ann(x) \ne ann(y)$.

I have a broad question: is there any necessary and sufficient condition to have $ab = 0$?

Kindly share your thoughts or some references. Thank you.

Comment: Seems like there is no useful connection... $ab=0$ iff $a\in ann(b)$, and it's hard to see what $x$ and $y$ have to do with anything.